# Add pseudo column in select statement

Tags: postgresql

I have following data in table `student`

| s_id | s_subject | s_marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 30 |
| 2 | Hindi | 50 |

How I want to represent

| s_id | s_name | s_subject | s_marks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Student | English | 30 |
| 2 | Student | Hindi | 50 |

This s_name should come as `Student` for all the `s_id`. Basically I want to mask the student_name

`SELECT s_id, s_subject, s_marks FROM student` will give me what in table, now how to add extra column in select statement with a mask name... One extra column with same value throughout...

> Edit: This was stupid question. Still keeping this here so to help stupid people like me.

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT s_id, 'Student' as s_name ,s_subject, s_marks FROM student` ?

Comment: I feel stupid now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s_id, 'Student' as s_name ,s_subject, s_marks FROM student
```